# Single Cell Name Extraction in Excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have an excel spreadsheet where I have first and last name in a single cell. 
I want to extract the first name and first initial from their last name into another cell.  What is the most efficient way to do this?

John Smith = John S

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1,1)+1)
```

Drag/Copy down as required. See image for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Split your column into two based on space as delimiter. This will give you column1 with first name and column2  with last name.

step 2: use formula to concatenate both as required: 
formula =CONCATENATE(column1, " ", MID(column2,1,1))

column1     column2      output
vaishali    thakur      vaishali t